# IOS - Make background fetch Occurs only once a day (No need for specific time)

Tags: ios, xcode, scheduling, nstimeinterval, background-fetch

I'm using background fetch to schedule task.
If i understood correctly background fetch happens many times during the day.
I need to limit it to occur only one time during the day.
Everything is set up correctly,For now i have setted (as a temp value) the

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
```

Any suggestions how can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your background fetch handler, check the date it was last performed, if that time was yesterday, perform a new fetch and store the time of the next check. Figuring out if the date was yesterday takes a little work:

```
// assumes oldDate is the last time it was actually fetched
let now = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let components = cal?.components(.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate:oldDate , toDate: now, options: .WrapComponents)
let days = components?.day
if days? > 0 {
    doActualFetch()
    self.oldDate = now
}
```

You'll probaby want to unwrap your optionals better than I did, but that should get you moving.

Your handler will still get called multiple times per day, but you can use this to skip doing the actual fetch.

Comment: Awesome, i'll try that! + Another question, does background fetch occurs minimum once a day? i mean there is situation that it occurs every 2 days or even a week?

Comment: Good Doug? any chance you can answer wha i have asked above?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that for sure.